# How to display the data that came to the server?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I create a chat, using the post method I send the data from the form to the server, and then redirect to the chat page. I have a block that should have the username entered on the registration page, how do I display it on the page? At the moment I'm doing this through local storage.

index.js

```
app.post('/', urlencodedParser, function (
    request,
    response
) {
    if (!request.body)
        return response.sendStatus(400);
    response.redirect("client/chat.html");
    console.log(request.body.Username);
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {

    socket.on('chat message', (msg) => { 
....
```

That's how it goes now
register.js:

```
const FORM = document.querySelector(".FORM");
const INPUT = document.querySelector(".INPUT");


FORM.addEventListener('submit', (Event) => {
    Event.preventDefault();
    if (INPUT.value) {
        let name = INPUT.value;
        localStorage.setItem("name", name);
        Event.target.reset();
    }
});
```

main.js:

```
const userName = localStorage.getItem('name');
nameBlock.innerHTML = userName;
```

How can I display it so that the server sends a request to the main and inserts it there with the help of innerHTML

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeYWa.png)

Comment: register.js doe snot seem to be making any API call. Also where is your main/index etc. What kind of app is this on the UI and what is the folder strucutre?

Comment: Added structure to the question, index.js is the main file (this is the server). How can I contact the server and get the data that is in the app.post?

Comment: You will have to use socket.io-client in the UI. It will be receiving the data, similar to yoru server

Comment: I do this, but in main.js file, I'm wondering how can I get data from app .post, how can I get my username from there? How can I contact the server to provide them to me?